# check if user in group ActiveDirectory.js node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, active-directory

In c# I would write something like this:

```cs
bool HasRole(string userName, string[] groupNames)
{
    var ad = new ActiveDirectory();
    return groupsNames.Any(groupName => ad.IsUserInGroup(userName, groupName);
}
```

and then just

```cs
if (HasRole("UserName", new[] {"group1", "group2"}))
    //do something
```

in javascript it looks like all things are doing asynchronously, I've read about promises and so on, and tried this:

```js
const ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory2');
const Promise = require('promise');
const globals = require('./globals');
const activeDirectory = new ActiveDirectory(globals.AdConfig);

hasRole(msg, ...groupNames) {
        if (groupNames == null || groupNames == undefined || groupNames.length == 0)
            return false;
        let promises = [];
        groupNames.forEach(groupName => {
            let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                activeDirectory.isUserMemberOf(msg.envelope.user.name, groupName, function (err, isMember) {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err)
                    }
                    resolve(isMember);
                });
            });
            promises.push(promise);
        });
        //I don't clearly understand how I can return promise result only or promise with the right result
        let hasRole = false;
        promises.forEach(promise => promise.done(result => {
            if (result)
                hasRole = result;
        }));
        return hasRole;
```

So how can write something like:

```js
if (hasRole(msg, 'group1', 'group2'))
    //do something...
```

I suppose I should return `promise` but how I can do it if i need to check multiple groups?

**UPDATE**

I wrapped the `forEach` loop in promise:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            promises.forEach(promise => promise.done(result => {
                if (result)
                    return resolve(result);
            }));
```

and then:

```
hasRole(msg, 'group1', 'group2').done(result => {
    if (result)
       //do...
});
```

May there is another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution. [Promises.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) is what i needed.

Result code:

```js
hasRole(msg, ...groupNames) {
        let promises = [];
        groupNames = groupNames.filter(x => x.trim().length > 0);
        if (groupNames == undefined || groupNames.length == 0)
        {
            promises.push(new Promise.resolve(false));
            return Promise.all(promises);
        }
        groupNames.forEach(groupName => {
            let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                activeDirectory.isUserMemberOf(msg.envelope.user.name, groupName, function (err, isMember) {
                    if (err) {
                        reject(err)
                    }
                    resolve(isMember);
                });
            });
            promises.push(promise);
        });
        return Promise.all(promises);
    }
```